# Replace nested loop

Tags: python, binary

This code takes a little more time to execute , How to make it faster.

```
from numpy import array_split
x ="01001111 01101101"
x = x.replace(" " ,"")

l = [ int(i) for i in str(x)]
l = [list(t) for t in 
array_split(l,len(l)//8)]

char = " "

for lis in l:
   total = 0
   b = 1
   for i in range(len(lis)):
        x = (-1 - i)
        total += lis[x] * b
        b *= 2
    
    char += chr(total)
print(char)
```

Is it because of numpy array_split,
Any other way to make sublist within list without using numpy array_split?
What can I replace nested loop with?

Comment: No I am not trying to revert.

Comment: It converts binary to string

Comment: Maybe just use builtins? `int(x.replace(' ', ''), 2)` will convert your string to integer supposing it's written in binary system

Comment: Will it make the code faster?

Comment: Ough, sorry, I just understood what you were trying to do... You have a binary string and want to convert every byte (separated by space) to a char? Then `''.join(chr(int(e,2)) for e in x.split(' '))` will work. And it will be faster, and significantly, I hope. It will produce "Om" for your input (note that spaces should not be removed from string).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to revert the bytes?

```
' '.join(
        [byte[::-1] for byte in x.split(' ')]
    )
```

Besides, your code is far from ok, way far.